# Use of __stdcall with a C++ DLL

Tags: c++, excel, dll

I'm creating a C++ dll for Excel and have been successfully using "__stdcall" in front of the C++ functions that Excel will call.  However, some of these dll functions call on other functions within the dll to perform calculations and I'm getting inaccurate returns.

Does stdcall make functions "invisible" to calls from within the dll?

Chris

Comment: "I'm getting inaccurate returns" is not a good problem description.

Comment: Short answer is no. Longer answer is that your inaccurate returns are probably caused by bugs in your code.

Comment: @LRiO, By inaccurate returns, I mean it appears an internal function call is not happening.  Specifically, I'm supposed to get latitude/longitude in decimal degrees but am instead getting huge numbers that look like ECEF values.  It appears the call to the internal function that converts ECEF to lat/lon is being ignored.

Comment: Is this 32- or 64-bit code?

Comment: @MatsPetersson -- 32 bit.

Comment: Ok, if it was 64-bit I would have pointed out that `__stdcall` doesn't make any difference at all (there is no such thing in 64-bit). I still think the problem is elsewhere, so I would suggest that you post a small example of how it's going wrong (something that returns a simple value).

Answer (score 0):

OK, it was just a stupid transposition in my code causing the problem, but "__stdcall" does not affect function calls internal to the dll (C++).

Chris